# In VS Code, can one run Python code in an integrated Python terminal like in Spyder?

Tags: python, command-line, visual-studio-code, spyder

Currently, in Visual Studio Code (under Windows 10 64bits), at a Python file called `path\myfile.py`, if one clicks with mouse right-button for context menu and then chooses 'Run Python File in Terminal', an integrated CMD terminal is open and file is automatically run there with:

```
python.exe path\myfile.py
```

After the file stops running, one is naturally left at the integrated CMD cursor.

This behavior is quite different, for instance, from what one has with an IDE like Spyder. There, when you run code (e.g. with `F5`), at the end one is left still at the Python cursor and can access content of variables created when code was run.

Is there a way to achieve a similar behavior in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Use the `-i` command line option https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i?

Comment: @UnholySheep I know that is an option if I run python code from a CMD terminal directly. Question is: in case that solves the problem, how to configure Visual Studio Code to send files to terminal with such an option enabled?

Comment: The (probably) best way would be to create a custom launch configuration: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations (and then launch using `F5`)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure VS Code Python extension to use the `-i` command line option
Described in https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i

You only have to add the setting bellow (inside `settings.json` file)

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-i"],
```

This will execute the command `python.exe -i path\myfile.py`.
I don't know if it is a new feature, but I've been using it for while.

If you would like to use the terminal **IPython, like in Spyder**, you can use a different set of options, as the following:

```
"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-m","IPython","-i"],
```

With these, VS Code will execute the command `python.exe -m IPython -i path\myfile.py`.
Then, it will run `IPython` module as a "script" (with `-m` option), which will use the options `-i path\myfile.py`, i.e., IPython will run the file and remain opened.

---

BTW, another thing is: you can run "cells" in Spyder's integrarted terminal (regions of code with `#%%`). But in VS Code it seems you can't.

I've made a question with a "work around" to run cells of Python files in VS Code Integrated terminal, which is posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275551/python-in-vs-code-can-i-run-cell-in-the-integrated-terminal/61444964#61444964)

Comment: I tried this, and its pretty good. The problem is that when you try to run another file (after the first run leaves behind an IPython prompt), you get an error `NameError: name 'python' is not defined` and you have to run `quit` again. This is somewhat frustrating. Is there a way, using VS Code settings, to run the file within the IPython prompt using `%run`, something like Spyder's `runfile()`

Comment: Hi @Astro. I tried to do exactly what you're asking: run files in an IPython terminal, using VS Code, like in Spyder, but there's no direct way. Even so, I managed to do it with [this macro extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros). I've put the needed settings in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Diogo-Rossi/66cd423f8d849ce2eeed3c1f8f123502) for you, which has the macro `runInIPythonTerminal` and a config to put IPython as default terminal profile. The important thing to do is to send the magic comand `%run` to the IPython terminal with the file name.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely check it out, it seems to be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can come is to run the code under the debugger and set a breakpoint at the end to pause the exiting of the execution. Otherwise feel free to file a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Open a terminal window and it's like a terminal window on your computer. You can type `python filepathandname` and the python script will execute like it does from the command line.

Comment: But then you can't send code from the editor to that terminal.